# How to convert string to bytes but keep the linefeed in Python3?

Tags: python

Originally I have python 2.7 code, which can read a file and deliver it to perl code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["perl", _conlleval], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, _ = proc.communicate(open(filename).read())
```

Now I would like to convert it to Python3 code, but in Python3 `proc.communicate` reads bytes-like object rather than 'str'. So I use `stdout, _ = proc.communicate(open(filename).read().encode())`, but it turns out that all the line feeds in will file be converted to `\n`, for example, in the file I have

```
Apple
Tree

Is 
Good
```

But unfortunately the encode will make it:

```
Apple\nTree\n\nIs\nGood\n
```

How could I correct this error? I want to send the byte format stuff to pearl without those `\n`

Comment: What do you want it to *send*?  What do you want the newlines to be converted to?

Comment: Have you tried messing around with the [`newline` parameter for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)? Have you tried to open the file in binary mode and send it that way? Those newline characters are in the file, you might have to strip/filter them out.  Better yet, convert your perl script to Python and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `repr`: It returns a string containing a printable representation of an object.

```
stri='''Apple
Tree

Is
Good
'''
print(stri)
print(repr(stri))
```

output:

```
Apple
Tree

Is
Good

'Apple\nTree\n\nIs \nGood\n'
```

Comment: repr does not change the type of it. It is still string

Comment: What operation you want to be done on the string? Remove new lines?